# Javascript input event doesn't fire on pasting whitespace

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to make a word counter/limiter for input/textarea fields. I believe I've got my logic working pretty well. I have a function running on the `input` event which serves to both update the remaining words counter, but also handle cases where content is changed without a keypress (E.g. paste operation).

This event is being fired if I try to copy a few words and paste them in (the event fires and the value is truncated). However, I've found that if I copy and paste whitespace only, the event doesn't fire.

Does anyone know why the event wouldn't fire on pasting whitespace? Is there a better event I can listen on to pickup this behaviour.

This is mostly out of personal interest, not for a real project. So my JS isn't very friendly with older browsers.

```js
function limitFieldKeyDown(event) {
  const maxWords = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-word-limit'), 10);
  // See what character was entered.
  let pressedKey = event.key;
  // Check against special keys
  if (pressedKey.length > 1) {
    pressedKey = '';
  }
  // Get text (including pressed key).
  const text = `${this.value}${pressedKey}`.trim();
  // Get the count of words
  let words;
  if (text === '') {
    // Handle special case of empty string
    words = [];
  }
  else {
    words = text.split(/\s+/);
  }

  const currentWordCount = words.length;
  if (currentWordCount >= maxWords) {
    // Detect if the word was whitespace.
    if (pressedKey !== pressedKey.trim()) {
      // On last word, no more spaces.
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}

function truncateToWords(text, words, limit) {
  let currentIndex = 0;
  // Find the character position which matches the current word limit.
  for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    currentIndex = text.indexOf(words[i], currentIndex) + words[i].length;
  }
  // Truncate the text to position.
  return text.substring(0, currentIndex);
}

function limitFieldInput() {
  const maxWords = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-word-limit'), 10);
  let text = this.value.trim();
  let words;
  if (text === '') {
    // Handle special case of empty string
    words = [];
  }
  else {
    words = text.split(/\s+/);
  }
  let currentWordCount = words.length;
  // Check if text is longer than maximum
  if (currentWordCount > maxWords) {
    // Longer than maximum, truncate.
    text = truncateToWords(text, words, maxWords);
    // Update variables with truncated text.
    this.value = text;
    words = text.split(/\s+/);
    currentWordCount = words.length;
  }

  // Update the word counter.
  const counterFields = this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('span.word-limit');
  if (counterFields.length > 0) {
    const remainingWords = maxWords - currentWordCount;
    for (let i = 0; i < counterFields.length; ++i) {
      counterFields[i].innerText = `${remainingWords} remaining`;
    }
  }
}

function limitField(field) {
  field.addEventListener('keydown', limitFieldKeyDown);
  field.addEventListener('input', limitFieldInput);
  const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown');
  field.dispatchEvent(event);
  const event2 = new Event('input');
  field.dispatchEvent(event2);
}

const limtiedFields = document.querySelectorAll('textarea.word-limit');

for (let i = 0; i < limtiedFields.length; ++i) {
  // Run on every keydown event.
  limitField(limtiedFields[i]);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea class="word-limit" data-word-limit="5"></textarea>
  <span class="word-limit"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the logic here:

```
if (pressedKey !== pressedKey.trim()) {
  // On last word, no more spaces.
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

`pressedKey` is equal to `" "` when it's a whitespace, either copy+pasted or just from the spacebar, but `pressedKey.trim()` is equal to `""`, so you are preventing the rest of the event listeners from triggering.

Comment: I tried disabling this section of code but it doesn't seem to be the cause. `event.preventDefault()` shouldn't stop the event propagation.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution to my issue. The `input` event was firing on pasting whitespace. The following if statement was the issue.

```
// Check if text is longer than maximum
if (currentWordCount > maxWords) {
  // Longer than maximum, truncate.
  text = truncateToWords(text, words, maxWords);
  // Update variables with truncated text.
  this.value = text;
  words = text.split(/\s+/);
  currentWordCount = words.length;
}
```

I needed to change the if statement to `>=`. This causes the truncating to occur when at the maximum number of words, instead of only when past the maximum.